# Is there a way to break into the debugger when an AngularJS expression is running?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

If I have this select: `<select name="custType" ng-model="vm.custType" ng-options="c.name.toUpperCase() as c.name for c in vm.customers"...>`

Is there a way to break into the devtools debugger when the expression inside ng-options starts to run?
**Different reasons**:
 - I would like to know when the expression runs during the lifecycle of the web page.
 - I would like to know the current values of c.name and vm.customers at
   a point of time during the expression lifecycle.
  - I also want to know if vm.customers is being used before it gets loaded with data.

Answer (score 0):

find ng-options directive at angular src code and place a breakpoint.

[ng-options](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/bf758d0bef449e07ce57d9c53dcb2a9191c1dc3d/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L597)

Answer (score 0):

Have a try using the following:

**HTML**

```
 <select name="custType"
         ng-model="vm.custType"
         ng-options="c.name.toUpperCase() as c.name for debugCustomer(c) in vm.customers"
  ... ></select>
```

**JS**

```
...

$scope.debugCustomer = function (customer) {
  console.log(customer);
  debugger;
  return customer;
}

...
```